# RecyclerView expand/collapse items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, expand

I want to expand/collapse the items of my recyclerView in order to show more info. I want to achieve the same effect of the [SlideExpandableListView](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView).

Basically in my viewHolder I have a view that is not visible and I want to do a smooth expand/collapse animation rather than set the visibility to VISIBLE/GONE only. I only need an item to be expanded at a time and it would be cool to have some elevation to show that the item is selected.

It is the same effect of the new Android recent calls history list. The options "CALL BACK" and "DETAILS" are visible only when an item is selected.

[image: RecyclerView expandable items]

Comment: I have a related question. In the Clock app, alarm set activity has a similar feature. Is it done the same way?

Comment: Hey have you got the solution? i am also looking for the same solution for my app.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I've updated the recommended way of doing it according to Google I/O 2016. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items/38623873#38623873

Comment: check my answer here a simple and cool solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092441/5962715

Answer (score 216):

Please don't use any library for this effect instead use the recommended way of doing it according to Google I/O. In your recyclerView's **onBindViewHolder** method do this:

```
final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

- Where **details** is my view that will be displayed on touch (call details in your case. Default Visibility.GONE).
- **mExpandedPosition** is an int variable initialized to -1

And for the cool effects that you wanted, use these as your list_item attributes:

```
android:background="@drawable/comment_background"
android:stateListAnimator="@animator/comment_selection"
```

where comment_background is:

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="true"
android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/selected_comment_background" />
<item android:drawable="@color/comment_background" />
</selector>
```

and comment_selection is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_activated="true">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="@dimen/z_card"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in" />
</item>

<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in" />
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: where is the video of this ？

Comment: If one expanded then the other collapses

Comment: When using this code the expand-animation looks weird. Everytime the top item disappears and everything shifts up one position. Have you ever experienced something similar?

Comment: @Vacutainer yep. Any fixes?

Comment: Not an official google project. It was a sample from a google engineer "Nick Butcher" who played around with new animation features for demo purposes.

Comment: I get exactly the same issue with the whole list looking weird when selecting it. Might have to relook at how I've got my list setup.

Also, the stateListAnimator isn't available on Pre-21 devices which isn't that good for anyone using AppCompat :/

So, this doesn't work.

Comment: Just to add that notifyItemChanged(position) works better than notifyDataSetChanged(). Less clunky, but still not entirely right

Comment: I try to do the animation but I implement this on the adapter, but what would be the solution to the `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);` if I cannot hace the recycler view reference.

Comment: @Ranveer It works kind of. I have two quite similar recyclerViews, but it only works correctly for one. No idea why.
@MartínDaniel You need to pass the `recyclerView` as a parameter in the constructor for the adapter

Comment: This is an awful approach. I can't believe it was recommended at Google I/O. Even after investigating the Plaid project and implementing all the required workarounds from it, the animation still causes some major glitches in RecyclerView, e.g. first/last visible item disappearing prematurely. Also scrolling while the animation runs messes all things badly. In general, I don't think fixing all the issues caused by this approach may be called "just put one line and everything will just work" as advertised.

Comment: I have used this and i have two other list in the child view. This is taking more than 2 seconds to expand and this approach doesn't seems to be useful when you have complex things in your child view. Any other approach for accordion?

Comment: Very helpful but any idea about animation duration respect to material design guideline?

Comment: When there are few items in list this approach is working fine. But items exceeds screen, glitch like reloading screen, moving elements starts to happen. Is there solution for this?

Comment: Do we have some more fresh & easy way in 2019 for this issue?

Comment: Due to first item set as GONE the child button click is not functional and works when any other item is clicked.

Comment: The smoothest recyclerview expand/collapse animation I saw is here: https://proandroiddev.com/complex-ui-animation-on-android-8f7a46f4aec4

Comment: Does anyone have a complete running example code? Please post a link here if you have an example project to solve this issue?

Comment: I wonder how this is the most up-voted answer, first of all it's bad practice memory-wise to implement click listener inside `onBindViewHolder` and second calling `notifyDataSetChanged` is way too wrong because that causes whole recyclerview to be refreshed when in reality only one item is changed.

Answer (score 105):

For this, just needed simple lines not complicated

in your onBindViewHolder method add below code

```
final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
});
```

> **mExpandedPosition** is an int  global variable initialized to -1

### **For those who want only one item expanded and others get collapsed. Use this**

first declare a global variable with previousExpandedPosition = -1

then

```
    final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
    holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
    holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);

    if (isExpanded)
       previousExpandedPosition = position;

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
            notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: great solution. Also I'd recommend to move setting `OnClickListener`s to `onCreateViewHolder` instead of `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Works very well, about time there was a decent solution that just lets the `RecyclerView` do the work, I mean, whats the point of the `LayoutManager` otherwise if it doesn't manage the layouts!  This solution is better than the top voted solution as it has less code, lets the `RecyclerView` handle things and works better!

Comment: did not quite understand how to add "details" view. Should it be static for each holder? What if for each list items I need to add different views?

Comment: @BekaBot it is the view that you want to hide during collapsing item

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph yes, I understand. In this case the view should be the same for all items? What if I want different views for different items?

Comment: @BekaBot, in this case, I showed only one view.  You should make it appropriate for you.

Comment: This works well however if there are any images present in the row then they will flicker. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph : your solution works perfectly fine but images in my row item flicker as I expand and collapse the view. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph I guess the flicker is due to updating the adapter again the second time with `notifyItemChanged(position);`. What exactly does this line of code acheive? I'm a beginner, hope you don't mind. Thanks

Comment: how dynamically loading web api data for expand and collapse please helpme

Comment: This works like a charm, but I have an icon to indicate the expand and collapse, I trying to use a rotate animation `mExpandArrow.animate().rotation(rotationAngle).setDuration(500).start(); `, with notifyItemChanged I lose the animation, how can I fix this?

Comment: @Kiran Benny Joseph ... Grt !! Simple and perfect solution.

Comment: perfecto, thank you @KiranBennyJoseph , upvoted for saving my day.

Comment: Is it possible to move this to ViewHolder.bind()?

Answer (score 76):

Not saying this is the best approach, but it seems to work for me.

The full code may be found at:
Example code at:  https://github.com/dbleicher/recyclerview-grid-quickreturn

First off, add the expanded area to your cell/item layout, and make the enclosing cell layout animateLayoutChanges="true".  This will ensure that the expand/collapse is animated:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llCardBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="This is a long title to show wrapping of text in the view."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="My subtitle..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llExpandArea"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:text="Item One" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:text="Item Two" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, make your RV Adapter class implement View.OnClickListener so that you can act on the item being clicked.  Add an int field to hold the position of the one expanded view, and initialize it to a negative value:

```
private int expandedPosition = -1;
```

Finally, implement your ViewHolder, onBindViewHolder() methods and override the onClick() method.  You will expand the view in onBindViewHolder if it's position is equal to "expandedPosition", and hide it if not.  You set the value of expandedPosition in the onClick listener:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int colorIndex = randy.nextInt(bgColors.length);
    holder.tvTitle.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    holder.tvTitle.setBackgroundColor(bgColors[colorIndex]);
    holder.tvSubTitle.setBackgroundColor(sbgColors[colorIndex]);

    if (position == expandedPosition) {
        holder.llExpandArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.llExpandArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    String theString = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());

    // Check for an expanded view, collapse if you find one
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Set the current position to "expanded"
    expandedPosition = holder.getPosition();
    notifyItemChanged(expandedPosition);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked: "+theString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Create a ViewHolder to represent your cell layout
 * and data element structure
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvSubTitle;
    LinearLayout llExpandArea;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
        llExpandArea = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llExpandArea);
    }
}
```

This should expand only one item at a time, using the system-default animation for the layout change.  At least it works for me.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I know how to keep only one item selected. I don't really know how to do the animation on that item. The expand/collapse animation with the default system animation doesn't look very smooth.

Comment: I haven't tried the following yet, but it sure looks like it will work.  Check out the answer at:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26443762/2259418

Comment: I have a related question. In the Clock app, alarm set activity has a similar feature. Is it done the same way?

Comment: @user2731584 - I don't think so.  Looking at (what I believe is) their source, it appears that the Lollipop clock is using a ListView to display the list of alarms. Layout: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/android-5.0.1_r1/res/layout/alarm_clock.xml
They appear to have custom code to animate the expand/collapse items in this list.  See the following source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/android-5.0.1_r1/src/com/android/deskclock/AlarmClockFragment.java

Comment: Thanks for the links. I didn't know the app sources were available.

Comment: @MojoTosh you are right. They are using ListView and doing the animation using code. `expandAlarm` function in `AlarmClockFragment.java` files executes the expansion part.

Comment: I would recommend all people to peep the example at least once if you face any issue as this code is too little to make everything working. Anyways, well done.

Comment: Works like a charm. Is there a way to change the duration (/speed) of the animation?

Comment: Which `onClick()` should I override? There's no `onClick` in the Adapter.

Comment: when i click item expanded, i want click on this item again for collapse how can i do that?

Comment: @vleong Please go through [this file](https://github.com/dbleicher/recyclerview-grid-quickreturn/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/examplersqr/RVAdapter.java) for understanding the implementation of `onClickListener`

Answer (score 17):

There is a very simple to use library with gradle support: https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout.

Right from the library docs:

```
<net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:el_duration="1000"
    app:el_expanded="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click here to toggle expansion" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Fixed height"
        app:layout_expandable="true" />

 </net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLinearLayout>
```

After you mark your *expandable* views, just call any of these methods on the container: `expand()`, `collapse()` or `toggle()`

Comment: Is this still the best way to do it? I am trying to follow what you wrote. I have some recycle views that I want to expand to show a graph when clicked on

Answer (score 12):

I know it has been a long time since the original question was posted. But i think for slow ones like me a bit of explanation of @Heisenberg's answer would help.

Declare two variable in the adapter class as

```
private int mExpandedPosition= -1;
private RecyclerView recyclerView = null;
```

Then in **onBindViewHolder** following as given in the original answer.

```
      // This line checks if the item displayed on screen 
      // was expanded or not (Remembering the fact that Recycler View )
      // reuses views so onBindViewHolder will be called for all
      // items visible on screen.
    final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;

        //This line hides or shows the layout in question
        holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);

        // I do not know what the heck this is :)
        holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);

        // Click event for each item (itemView is an in-built variable of holder class)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

 // if the clicked item is already expaned then return -1 
//else return the position (this works with notifyDatasetchanged )
                mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
    // fancy animations can skip if like
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
    //This will call the onBindViewHolder for all the itemViews on Screen
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

And lastly to get the recyclerView object in the adapter override

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Great and simple solution. Small improvement, use RecyclerView.NO_POSITION rather than magic number -1.

Answer (score 10):

There is simply no need of using third party libraries. A **little tweak** in the method demonstrated in **Google I/O 2016** and Heisenberg on this topic, does the trick.

Since `notifyDataSetChanged()` **redraws the complete `RecyclerView`**, `notifyDataItemChanged()` is a better option (not the best) because we have the position and the `ViewHolder` at our disposal, and `notifyDataItemChanged()` only **redraws the particular `ViewHolder` at a given position**.

But the problem is that the premature disappearence of the `ViewHolder` upon clicking and it's emergence is not eliminated even if `notifyDataItemChanged()` is used.

The following code **does not** resort to `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyDataItemChanged()` and is Tested on API 23 and works like a charm when used on a RecyclerView where each ViewHolder has a `CardView` as it's root element:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final boolean visibility = holder.details.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE;

            if (!visibility)
            {
                holder.itemView.setActivated(true);
                holder.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (prev_expanded!=-1 && prev_expanded!=position)
                {
                    recycler.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(prev_expanded).itemView.setActivated(false);
                    recycler.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(prev_expanded).itemView.findViewById(R.id.cpl_details).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                prev_expanded = position;
            }
            else
            {
                holder.itemView.setActivated(false);
                holder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recycler);              
        }
});
```

`prev_position` is an global integer initialized to -1.
`details` is the complete view which is shown when expanded and cloaked when collapsed.

As said, the root element of `ViewHolder` is a `CardView` with `foreground` and `stateListAnimator` attributes defined exactly as said by Heisenberg on this topic.

**UPDATE:** The above demonstration will collapse previosuly expanded item if one of them in expanded. To modify this behaviour and keep the an expanded item as it is even when another item is expanded, you'll need the following code.

```
if (row.details.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE)
    {
        row.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        row.root.setActivated(true);
        row.details.animate().alpha(1).setStartDelay(500);
    }
    else
    {
        row.root.setActivated(false);
        row.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        row.details.setAlpha(0);
    }
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recycler);
```

**UPDATE:** When expanding the last items on the list, it may not be brought into full visibility because the expanded portion goes below the screen. To get the full item within screen use the following code.

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recycler.getLayoutManager();
    int distance;
    View first = recycler.getChildAt(0);
    int height = first.getHeight();
    int current = recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(first);
    int p = Math.abs(position - current);
    if (p > 5) distance = (p - (p - 5)) * height;
    else       distance = p * height;
    manager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, distance);
```

**IMPORTANT:** For the above demonstrations to work, one must keep in their code an instance of the RecyclerView & it's LayoutManager (the later for flexibility)

Comment: Thanks this solution works for me. I try to avoid using `notifyItemChanged` because I have an `ImageView` which load image from an url. `notifyItemChanged` reload my image makes it looks weird

Comment: The line that nails it is `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recycler);`, great find. But I found out that by using this method, if I spam-click several rows sequentially, it eventually triggers an internal crash `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`. I imagine this is due to the view recycling on the recycler view bounds, but I can't tell for sure.

Did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Is this still the best way to do it? I am trying to follow what you wrote. I have some recycle views that I want to expand to show a graph when clicked on. I am having a hard time understanding exactly what to do

Comment: Does anyone have the complete example of this implementation? I mean a working code example. Please help. I am unable to understand how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

After using the recommended way of implementing expandable/collapsible items residing in a `RecyclerView` on [RecyclerView expand/collapse items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623873/4039908) answered by [HeisenBerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180959/heisenberg), I've seen some noticeable artifacts whenever the `RecyclerView` is refreshed by invoking `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup)` and subsequently `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

His original answer:

```
final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Modified:

```
final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;
holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mExpandedHolder != null) {
            mExpandedHolder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notifyItemChanged(mExpandedPosition);
        }
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : holder.getAdapterPosition();
        mExpandedHolder = isExpanded ? null : holder;
        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

- **details** is view that you want to show/hide during item expand/collapse
- **mExpandedPosition** is an `int` that keeps track of expanded item
- **mExpandedHolder** is a `ViewHolder` used during item collapse

Notice that the method `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup)` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` are replaced by `notifyItemChanged(int)` to target specific item and some little tweaks.

After the modification, the previous unwanted effects should be gone. However, this may not be the perfect solution. It only did what I wanted, eliminating the eyesores.

**::EDIT::**

For clarification, both `mExpandedPosition` and `mExpandedHolder` are globals.

Comment: Please explain how and where mExpandedHolder is declared and used?

Comment: @Werner I've edited the answer to show where it is declared. The usage is within the snippet itself as well as the purpose. It is used to animate collapsing, expanded item.

Comment: I love this approach the most as far as the animations is concerned, but I'm having this small "fade" when clicking the item. Do you have that as well or differently put, is this due to using notifyItemChanged()? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GaU1fcjHEfSErYF50otQGLGsIWkSyQSe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes. Like you have guessed, it is caused by `notifyItemChanged()`. You may manually animate and change the item height and add views into it.

Comment: @ChanTeckWei: your solution is working fine but row image flicker whenever I collapse or expand the recyclerview item row..Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised that there's no concise answer yet, although such an expand/collapse animation is very easy to achieve with just 2 lines of code:

```
(recycler.itemAnimator as SimpleItemAnimator).supportsChangeAnimations = false // called once
```

together with

```
notifyItemChanged(position) // in adapter, whenever a child view in item's recycler gets hidden/shown
```

So for me, the explanations in the link below were really useful: https://medium.com/@nikola.jakshic/how-to-expand-collapse-items-in-recyclerview-49a648a403a6

Comment: Its pretty simple and easy to implement. But it seems like expand animation is broken for the only last item of recycler view.

Comment: Awesome answer thanks buddy. I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following after you set the onClick listener to the ViewHolder class:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int originalHeight = yourLinearLayout.getHeight();
        animationDown(YourLinearLayout, originalHeight);//here put the name of you layout that have the options to expand.
    }

    //Animation for devices with kitkat and below
    public void animationDown(LinearLayout billChoices, int originalHeight){

        // Declare a ValueAnimator object
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
        if (!billChoices.isShown()) {
            billChoices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            billChoices.setEnabled(true);
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, originalHeight+originalHeight); // These values in this method can be changed to expand however much you like
        } else {
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight+originalHeight, 0);

            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f); // Fade out

            a.setDuration(200);
            // Set a listener to the animation and configure onAnimationEnd
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    billChoices.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    billChoices.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            // Set the animation on the custom view
            billChoices.startAnimation(a);
        }
        valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                billChoices.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                billChoices.requestLayout();
            }
        });


        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

**I think that should help, that's how I implemented and does the same google does in the recent call view.**

Answer (score 1):

```
//Global Variable

private int selectedPosition = -1;

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, final int i) {

        final int position = i;
        final GetProductCatalouge.details feedItem = this.postBeanses.get(i);
        customViewHolder.lly_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition = i;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if (selectedPosition == i) {

          if (customViewHolder.lly_hsn_code.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            customViewHolder.lly_hsn_code.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewHolder.lly_sole.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewHolder.lly_sole_material.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            customViewHolder.lly_hsn_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewHolder.lly_sole.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewHolder.lly_sole_material.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        } else {
            customViewHolder.lly_hsn_code.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewHolder.lly_sole.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewHolder.lly_sole_material.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use two view types in the your `RVAdapter`. One for expanded layout and other for collapsed.
And the magic happens with setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` for `RecyclerView`
Checkout the effect achieved using this at 0:42 in [this video](https://vimeo.com/201271481)

Comment: mind explaining this better? I can't seem to get it working

Comment: @sourlemonaid basically you create multiple view types for the list as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/3731795
 ... You keep a track of index for which the item is expanded, and the rest of the items are collapsed at that time. Now if(current_item_index == expanded_item_index) { return VIEW_TYPE_EXPANDED } else { reutrn VIEW_TYPE_COLLAPSED }

Answer (score -1):

#### Create your own Custom View

- If you wanted to you could create your own reusable custom View. [Here](https://dev.to/theplebdev/tap-to-expand-recyclerview-items-with-android-and-kotlin-3j20) is a quick and dirty example blog post I made on the subject. References are noted on the blog post

Answer (score -3):

This is easy, simple and work perfect for me, hope it help :

First : add this to viewgroup of item recyclerview

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Second : add this to your onclick method that expand or collapse current item :

```
val changeBounds = ChangeBounds()
// binder.contraintLayout is viewGroup that have animateLayoutChange = true (iam using databinding)
changeBounds.duration = binder.contrainLayout.layoutTransition.getDuration(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
changeBounds.interpolator = binder.contrainLayout.layoutTransition.getInterpolator(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
binder.expandView.Visibility = binder.expandView.Visibility != View.Visible
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binder.root.parent as ViewGroup, changeBounds)
```