# Expand and collapse CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

What is the proper way to expand a CardView?

[image: example]

Comment: its a expandable list view with cardview

Comment: Isn't there better solution ? Can't card view just expand itself ?

Comment: it can you just need to use wrap content as height of cardview and use textview inside it below title so on click make the textview visible and viceversa

Comment: Thank you, that worked great, but isn´t it bad design ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Use an expandable list view with cardview

**or even**

> You can use **wrap content** as **height** of **cardview** and use
> **textview** inside it below title, so on click make the textview **visible**
> and **vice-versa**.

but isn't it bad design ?

> nope it isn't if you give some transition or animation when it's expanded
> or collapsed
>
> If you want to see some default transition then just write **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"** in **parent layout**.

Comment: parent layout meaning the direct parent or the outermost layout? I am asking this because there is no effect of android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in my screen. Thank you in advance!

Comment: i applied to the outer most layout but there is no effect! What should i do?

Comment: @hetsgandhi can i see your code. then only i can tell what the problem might be.You can share a git link

Comment: No offense but android:animateLayoutChanges="true" doesn't give effect if i write in the outer most layout, i tried writing in direct outer layout, which works successfully! Thanks anyways!

Comment: refer to my answer, both good for expand and collapse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54156690/3260008

Answer (score 25):

If you are using CardViews inside a ListView or RecyclerView see my answer for recommended way of doing it:
[RecyclerView expand/collapse items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items/38623873#38623873)

If you are just using CardView then do this in your on onClickListener of cardview:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardview);
detailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

By default keep the visibility of your detailsView to be GONE in your xml.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. It looks good for expand. What transition would you apply to collapse the cardview? Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I used a cardview and an expand section **item_description** in the cardview. For the expand part I created a TextView below the header section (**LinearLayout/item_description_layout**) and when the user clicks on the header layout an expand/collapse method is called. Here is the code in the cardview:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/item_description_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:minHeight="48dp"
  android:paddingStart="16dp"
  android:paddingEnd="16dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_description_title"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.9"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:text="@string/description"/>

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/item_description_img"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/item_description"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingStart="16dp"
  android:paddingEnd="16dp"
  android:paddingBottom="16dp"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:visibility="gone"
  tools:text="description goes here"/>
```

Here is the method that is called. I also added a ObjectAnimator to handle the expand/collapse animation of the block. This is a simple animation that uses the length of the description text.

```
void collapseExpandTextView() {
    if (mItemDescription.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        // it's collapsed - expand it
        mItemDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mDescriptionImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_24dp);
    } else {
        // it's expanded - collapse it
        mItemDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mDescriptionImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_24dp);
    }

    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mItemDescription, "maxLines", mItemDescription.getMaxLines());
    animation.setDuration(200).start();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

just a line of code before setting `visibility GONE/ VISIBLE` can do:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition([the rootView containing the cardView], new AutoTransition());
```

no need to use the `animateLayoutChanges=true` in `XML` (this way also simple, but collapse behaviour is bad)

Answer (score 0):

I originally tried doing this by just adding an extra View to the bottom of my CardView and setting its visibility to gone ([*gone* vs *invisible*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)):

```
tools:visibility="gone"
```

Then, I set the CardView height to Wrap Content and added an icon with an onClickListener that changed the extra View's visibility to *visible*.

The issue with this was that even when the visibility was set to *gone*, my CardView was still behaving like the extra View was there.

To get around this, I explicitly set the visibility of the extra View to gone in my onBindViewHolder method:

```
holder.defPieces.visibility = View.GONE
```

After this, the expandable functionality worked how I wanted it to. I wonder if there's some odd order of operations that goes on when inflating a View to display in a RecyclerView.

Comment: The issue is with `tools` namespace. Value of the attribute is applied only in layout preview when it's prefixed with `tools`. You should change it to `android` to make it work in the app.

Answer (score -5):

```
mView.Click +=(sender, e) =>{
    LinearLayout temp = mView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LinerCart);
    if (vs == false) {
        temp.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        vs = true;
    } else {
        temp.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        vs = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -5):

I got the solution ( single cardview expandable listview )
    check this link
    http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/08/expandingcollapsing-recyclerview-row_18.html

if you add down arrow icon 
you just use my code

create xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_expand"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_description_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="toggle_contents"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Guest Conditions"
                    android:textColor="@color/hint_txt_color"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:textSize="16dp"/>

                 <ImageView
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:paddingTop="4dp"
                     android:paddingRight="10dp"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down"/>

                <!--content to hide/show -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_description"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/item_description_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/about_txt2"
                    android:textColor="@color/hint_txt_color"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    Mainactivity.java

     RelativeLayout layout_expand = (RelativeLayoutfindViewById(R.id.layout_expand);
     item_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_description);
     TextView item_description_title; 
    item_description_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_description_title);
    item_description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            animationUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
            animationDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);

            layout_expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(item_description.isShown()){
                        item_description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        item_description.startAnimation(animationUp);
                    }
                    else{
                        item_description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item_description.startAnimation(animationDown);
                    }
                }
            });

item_description_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(item_description.isShown()){
                    item_description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    item_description.startAnimation(animationUp);
                }
                else{
                    item_description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    item_description.startAnimation(animationDown);
                }
            }
        });
```