# Android CardView not animating properly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation, android-cardview

After implementing a `CardView` and trying to apply an animation to the arrow text view, the animation is showing unusual behaviour when the arrow is clicked. What can be done to fix the animation and get the result similar to the **Expected animation** image?

**Expected animation**

[image]

**Current animation**

[image]

**recyclerview_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardview_titlerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_A"
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_expandcollapsearrow"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_B"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**MyRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    private Context mContext;

    RecyclerViewHeader header;
    List<MyRecyclerItem> listItems;


    private Animation animationCollapse;
    private Animation animationExpand;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, RecyclerViewHeader header, List<MyRecyclerItem> listItems)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.header = header;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_header_expandcollapsebuttons, parent, false);
            return new MyRecyclerAdapter.VHHeader(v);
        }
        else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
            return new MyRecyclerAdapter.VHItem(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    private MyRecyclerItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(mContext, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);

        if (holder instanceof VHHeader)
        {
            VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader)holder;
        }
        else if (holder instanceof VHItem)
        {
            RecyclerViewListItemTransportConnections currentItem = getItem(position-1);
            final VHItem VHitem = (VHItem)holder;

            VHitem.txtA.setText(currentItem.getConnectionMode());
            VHitem.txtB.setText(currentItem.getConnectionName());

            VHitem.txtB.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);
            VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setTypeface(iconFont);

            VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (VHitem.txtB.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        VHitem.txtB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(180, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        rotate.setDuration(300);
                        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

                        VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.startAnimation(rotate);

                        VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);
                    } else {
                        VHitem.txtB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 180, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        rotate.setDuration(300);
                        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

                        VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.startAnimation(rotate);


TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(VHitem.cardview);

VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
            return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position)
    {
        return position == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size()+1;
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cardview;
        TextView txtExpandCollapseArrow, txtA, txtB;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.cardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);

            this.txtExpandCollapseArrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_expandcollapsearrow);

            this.txtA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_A);
            this.txtB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_B);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sourabh's suggestion**

[image]

Comment: Post your animation XML files as well.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal That was done programmatically

Comment: What are `R.anim.card_collapse` and `R.anim.card_expand`?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal ignore those they ain't suppose to be there

Comment: hello you have set animation only for `VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow`

Comment: for set visibility you need to set translate animation on `VHitem.txtB'
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454839/android-adding-simple-animations-while-setvisibilityview-gone)

Comment: @TejasTrivedi Yes, but I also need animation for the CardView itself. However I'm dealing with the arrow problem first unless someone knows how to fix both.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier approach would be to set the visibility of *hideable* views and use `TransitionManager` to animate those layout changes.

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView) 
// rootView can be the container view of all cards
```

This will take care of increasing card height and fading those views in. I am not sure if it'll handle rotating the arrow too, but you can try. or you can use `RotateAnimation` for it

Comment: Your suggestion helped a bit so many thanks, although there's a problem. The animation works perfectly when the CardView expands, but not when it collapses. Checkout the 'Sourabh's suggestion' screenshot. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Didn't dive into it too much but try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464629/expand-collapse-animation-in-cardview)

Answer (score -2):

The expected animation appears to be an vector drawable animation while the method that you have followed animates the view not the drawable .

You need to use [Animated Vector drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: It is not a vector drawable, it is a `TextView` containing a vector (FontAwesome)

Comment: Yes thats wat I siad , you are animating a texview presently but , one way in which   the effect can be achieved  is with animated vector drawable which animate  on vector drawables ( rather than the entire viewport ) , if you  could change to vector  icon.

Comment: using an imageview and setting the animated vector drawable as its background using srcCompact , should surely solve the problem of arrow animation atleast.