# Expand and Collapse cards in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

i'm working on a RecyclerView in Android which should contains expandable cards. I've already seen some questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items/38623873#38623873)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500322/expand-and-collapse-cardview) but I can't figure out how to manage some things.

In my app (pic below) the expandable part is the one with the "maps" icon and "plus" icon.

[Card expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtmYd.jpg)

During Google I/O 2016, [Nick Butcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjTJIDKT72M&feature=youtu.be&t=5m50s) explained some of his code but i can't solve the part in which he divides the layout in two parts (the one that is always visibile *itemView*, and the expandable one, *details*) in the onBindViewHolder method.

```
final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Can anyone explain me this and the other parts that make the animation and the expansion possible? You could find useful the Heisenberg's reply [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items/38623873#38623873) Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand/collapse animation in CardView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464629/expand-collapse-animation-in-cardview)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Solved: it was enough to identify the "hidden" part in a layout and save it inside the viewholder.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the hidden part in the viewholder constructor and inflating the view that manage it