# RecyclerView item resizing issues

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

So I have a RecyclerView with a bunch of CardView's that are set to expand on button press.
How I do it is by having a hidden layout (GONE) and when you press the expand button it will expand (or in other words make it visible) the layout. It uses the animations from animateLayoutChanges in XML.

The problem is that while the individual card being expanded animates properly, the other cards don't. If I expand or collapse one card, the rest immediately pop to their proper position with no animations. Where this proves troublesome in specific is when you collapse it. When you collapse the card it will immediately be under the card below it as the one below it hasn't animated.

How can I get these other cards to animate with the one being expanded?

As you can see in the gif below, since the card below it does not animate its movements, the top one ends up covered by the one below it and when expanding it the one below it is immediately pushed with no anims.

[Gif of my animation problem](https://gyazo.com/77df51f98b1f09b901be25703e04b9c0)

EDIT: I moved to using [this](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout) library for the Expandable layout and it has allowed me to bypass my problem all together and simply have one that works.

Comment: I recommend using this [View](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout) to make expandable areas, is better than using animateLayout.

Comment: @HenriqueCésarMadeira you were right that was much better. Doesn't solve the problem mentioned, but is a nice way to avoid it all together.

Answer (score 0):

I know it s too late to answer this question but you can do what you want by using `TransitionManager`.

this question gave me a great idea how to do it:

[RecyclerView expand/collapse items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items)