# Dismissible item on a list in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

do you know, what's the best practice to implement dismissible item on a RecyclerView or ListView?
I can see this UI pattern e.g. in settings app to close DataSaver.

[image: I can see this UI pattern e.g. in settings app to close DataSaver]

Comment: is this nested recyclerview?

Comment: I thinks is a expandable-recycler-view. Check out this : https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview

Comment: Might Help: [Expand a RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38623873/3142192)

Comment: I don't wanna expand, I wanna dismiss this item (action "TURN OFF" on battery saver item). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @qbait, You want to dismiss TURN OFF item on click?

Comment: no, I wanna dismiss the whole mint "battery saver" row item as it happens when you press "TURN OFF" in android settings

Comment: ok, I solved it. I made the RecyclerView with custom item and later implemented dismiss button that calls notifyItemRemoved(position);