# How to implement Accordion in Android?

Tags: android, accordion

I am looking for ways to implement Accordion view in Android.

I have tried with having a child and parent view inside recyclerview adapter and based on user action expand the hidden content inside the recyclerview item. I have used a custom linear layout manager to measure the height of the list dynamically and set that as height.

Any help is accepted. Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: It's called ExpandableListView

Comment: I do not want to use a ListView atleast. I used a recyclerview. But the problem was the design demands me to use nested recyclerview upto 3 levels which took so much time to load

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/draxdave/ConstraintAccordion) and you will find what you need.

[image]

Comment: An example or additional explanation to your answer is always helpful in making the answer more relevant and clear

Answer (score 0):

Android has a component called ExpandableListView - read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Can I use another list view inside the ExpandableListView

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. The ExpandableListView has a list of groups, clicking on a group will expand it to show it's children. It lets you set click listeners on the group as well as the child views. So if you're referring to the child views under a particular group as a list view, then yes, it is possible

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help - https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I have tried this intially when I started with this. As per this google i/o I have used recyclerview. Refer: https://youtu.be/EjTJIDKT72M?t=5m50s

Comment: also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items

Comment: It depends on your use case then. If you just have static options that will expand on clicking the item, the handling is easier to do. If it is a list, you might have to do a little more handling, so it's better to use the ExpandableListView. You can manage recycling of views manually by creating a viewholder and setting it as a tag on each view. If a view has a tag, simply reset the values on the fields, if it doesn't, create a new one.