# expand item of recycleView onclick and to collapse others

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cardview

i have a problem.

How to expand item of recycleView onclick and to collapse others when i use **few viewHolders and viewTypes** (all items can expanded). i use a library for details layout of item - [Expandable layout](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout)

and the second, how to raise/move item up to show all content?

thanks for any answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items

Comment: i saw it, but i need more explanation when i try to use few viewHolders @HemantParmar