# How to visible TextView in CardView?

Tags: android, cardview

I have a cardView in recyclerView, so I need to push the button "Explore" and open the cardView and see TextView, it is like [this example](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-behavior).

So, what should I use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using CardView, do this in your on onClickListener of cardview:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardview);
detailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

By default keep the visibility of your detailsView to be GONE in your xml.

If you are using CardViews inside a ListView or RecyclerView see answer for recommended way of doing it: [RecyclerView expand/collapse items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items/38623873#38623873)