# Expandable RecyclerView, having some items not expandable

Tags: android, user-interface, expandablerecyclerview

To show list of books in an Android App, I need an expandable RecyclerView, having "some" items expandable and some not, please check attachment.

I checked these libraries :

https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

I need a library to do this, but all of available libraries I found have all items expandable, not some of them.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell, what approach you have taken for Expandable RecyclerView ? Or you have used any library ?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?? please explain. you want a library or you want to know the logic?

Comment: `ExpandableRecyclerView` is not provided in APIs . If you are using a library  then you have to modify it in this way or maybe it comes with such behavior . Do you want to block expand if header view contains childs ?

Comment: Yes I need a library, sorry for insufficient description!

Comment: try this :https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView expand/collapse items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items)

Comment: try this ans :https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623873/8089770

Answer (score 0):

You can add onClickListener to the group item layout. In onClick just check if items need to be expanded. then expand the list. Otherwise not.

And another point, if your child list is empty, then it should not be expanded.It will happen automatically.