# How to change an another item's state in a RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView. Every layout contains expandle view within itself.
With item click expandle view of clicked item is expands. And if I'll click on two items there is will be two items with expanded view in my RecyclerView. I need to close others item's expandles view with item click. Only one item with expanded expandle view must be in recycler.

How do I can make this?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.exp.collapse();
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        holder.exp.expand();
    });
```

Comment: Could you post the code that handles the expanding of the items ?

Comment: good story! hmm

Comment: what's wrong?))

Comment: Hey OP, try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092441/5990846).

Comment: just taking a shot in the dark here, but perhaps create a global variable which holds your `holder` and each time the onClickListerner is hit do a check between the current holder and global one. If they are different call `exp.collapse()` on the global/old holder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the Position of previously expanded position make a property in lists object like some boolean isOpen or something set it to false or true as required now on Click of a new row

```
list.get(prevPosition).setIsOpen(false);
```

then

```
notifyItemChanged(prevPosition);
```

make sure you have handled in your bindViewHolder something like this

```
if(list.get(postition).getIsOpen()==false){
//hide your expanded list
}
```