# Animation on Recyclerview Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was going through this thread on this topic :
[RecyclerView Animation on Item Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642644/recyclerview-animation-on-item-click)

But I have one question on the technique used.
I tried implementing it based on solution above. Although the approach seems to work in the current view of my recyclerview. But as soon as i scroll further to Right (in my case its a Horizontal Recyclerview), i still see the view being expanded since the views are being recycled and the isExpanded value is still true for them. I was thinking shouldn't the isExpanded property be at the data being displayed, so that we don't keep the same state of the reused view ?

Curious to know, how does RecyclerView behaves when you scroll it to the next page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basically you need to check each item "state" and prepare the recycled viewholder for the new item to bind.

Please have a look at my `ExampleAdapter` (in `onBindViewHolder()`) in my FlexibleAdapter, where you can also find basic click and long click listener already implemented as example.

Feel free to ask questions.

Recently I've improved and created a **FlexibleAdapter** pattern for all RecyclerView.
Very simple to use, just copy 2 classes in your common files + some xml in order to enable the selection (Single/Multi) as it was for ListView.

Please have a look at the description and full working example: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter