# Inflate a view on click item from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

When I click in one item of a ListView I want to expand the item and show his data, inflating other view.
Using an ExpandableListView is okay for this case or there are better ways to do that?
If someone have any examples that would be great.

Comment: create custom listView with `+` and `-` as image. handle the click individually.

Comment: See [RecyclerView Animation on Item Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642644/recyclerview-animation-on-item-click) probably help u.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this lib https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView
it can be help you.