# How to populate a recyclerview on click of a button in a cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am struck into a situation where I am finding no way to proceed. Actually I have a RecyclerView of cardViews and there is an adapter that populates the card with data. I have to show some restaurants in the card. On click of a button in the Cardview, I have to show another recyclerview that will be populated with cardViews containing the branches of that restaurant.

Here i have just one Model that can return both type of data. I am not getting whether I should use 1 Adapter with multiple viewHolders or 2 Adapters. My View is also a single layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/recipient_card"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="20dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/receipient_card_height"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout">


                <ImageView
                    android:id ="@+id/arrow_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_info_icon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_info_icon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <com.inquirly.opinify.View.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/business_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/label_small"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:text="JustBake"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recipient_business_logo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/receipient_business_logo_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/receipient_business_logo_size"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/expand_button"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/height_button"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_button"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_recipient_branch_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visible= "false"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have made the inner recyclerView invisible in the beginning. When the user clicks on the arrow button in the main recycler's CardView button, the second recylerview should appear with the list of branches.

This is the screen shot of what i am trying to achieve.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do a implement a expandable `RecyclerView` instead. Check out [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=8f0cc3ff1f-Android_Weekly_165&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-8f0cc3ff1f-337834121) article. Also it's recommended that you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419161/expandable-list-with-recyclerview) question out.

Comment: Well.. I will try with this. However i got succeed with this but yes.. you are right...it's a pain to use a Nested recycler View... the inner recyclerview (if fetching dynamic data) will never adjust with height. Thanks anyway.