# RecyclerView with expandable items

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I need to make an expandable `RecyclerView`, with only one opened item per click (all others must close).
I know there is possibility to do this with the help of `ExpandableListView` and then use next code:

```
elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

but is there the way to make the same with using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I think this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419161/expandable-list-with-recyclerview    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/) is a nice tutorial for expending `RecyclerView` from [Big Nerd Ranch](https://www.bignerdranch.com/)

Summary:

- Define two layouts: One for parent items and one for child items.
- Define two ViewHolders for these layouts.
- Define two classes for parent and child objects.
- Parent object has to implement ParentObject interface.
- Define custom adapter.
- Call `setParentAndIconExpandOnClick(true)` on adapter.

For only one expanded view at a time, you can keep track of the last expanded view and close it when user cliced new one.

Comment: It just links to BigNerdRanch, not to the tutorial. But you are probably gonna link the same link I added.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add actual link :)

Comment: You are faster than me. I didn't notice your answer :)

Comment: thanks, but is there is some way to close all other items when one is open?

Comment: There is no default way. You have to keep list of expanded objects and close previous one when new one clicked.

Comment: Here's the way to easily track and implement only one open item per click
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40698779/3237960

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using some libraries, I'll recommend [Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview).  And [here](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/demo_e) is the example of expandable item.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way of tracking and implementing only one open item per click if using Expandable RecyclerView form big nerd ranch-

```
      Stack<Integer> mStack = new Stack<>();

     mRecyclerViewAdapter.setExpandCollapseListener(new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ExpandCollapseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onListItemExpanded(int position) {


                    try {
                        int x = mStack.pop();
                        mRecyclerViewAdapter.collapseParent(x);

                    } catch (EmptyStackException ex) {
                    }

                    mStack.push(position);


                }

                @Override
                public void onListItemCollapsed(int position) {

                    try {
                        mStack.pop();
                    } catch (EmptyStackException ex) {
                    }

                }
            });
```