# Similar custom expandable listviews in android application

Tags: android, listview

I would like to have a few similar expandable listviews in my android application across a few activities. They all have the same content, but use different designs. Some have buttons for example, and some not.

I would even want to have three expandable listviews that share **everything** except the background color for each cell.

Anyways, having a unique adapter for each listview seems like a bad design practice as they all very similar. I was thinking of making an abstract adapter and than extending it for every listview, would that work? Is there any other approach?

Thank you.

Comment: "I would even want to have three expandable listviews that share everything except the background color for each cell." - Sonds like only your layout resource is different. Use one adapter for all 3 listviews and pass your layout resource in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having a unique adapter for each listview seems like a bad design practice as they are all very similar.

That is correct. Duplicated code is almost always a sign of bad code design.

> I was thinking of making an abstract adapter and then extending it for every listview, would that work?

Yes.

> Is there any other approach?

Yes. E.g. if you want to have an adapter that supports different backgrounds, your adapter should take a background resource/color as constructor parameter. This approach fits for minor changes. If you want to have some non-expandable and some expandable listviews I would favor the inheritance approach.

---

> The problem is that some of my listviews would be expandable, so I could not use Recycler View.

Recyclerviews are a better design choice than listviews. Creating expandable ones isn't too hard, see [Expandable list with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419161/expandable-list-with-recyclerview).

Comment: Thank you! Since it's my first app and I don't have to deal with a ton of data, I would stick with basics (listView), but I would certainly keep in mind that RecyclerView is generally the better design choice